# Parallax works not smooth enough after mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, parallax

I am coming into this as a bit of a philistine so bear with me..

There are parallax scrolling effect and smooth scrolling on my page.

http://codepen.io/QLCee/pen/BWRMzd

Here is the I am trying to make
http://anagram.paris/team

My parallax scrolling effect is delayed after mouse scroll.
While I mouse scroll, and page and image moves smoothly down.
Page stops moving, but image still move for few millisecond

Is there anything more I could try?

Here is the code for smooth scroll

```
$(function(){
var $window = $(window);
var scrollTime = 1;
var scrollDistance = 200;

$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);

    TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
            ease: Power1.easeOut,
            overwrite: 5                            
        });
    });
});
```

This for PARALLAX

```
(function(){
 var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"), 
speed = 0.5;

window.onscroll = function(){
[].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

  var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
      elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

  el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

        });
    };
})();
```

Thank you

Comment: Step one: don't use scroll smoothing or anything else that modifies how the user's mouse interacts with the page, no one likes it and it will actively drive people away from your site.

Comment: http://anagram.paris/team　heres the one I am trying to make...